Do some chemicals degrade at low temperatures?
I was reading an article on how medicines degrade over time and how that could be a problem on a trip to Mars.
Which got me thinking. Surely the obvious solution is to store them at low temperatures. After all, space is COLD.
Which raises another questtion - can low temperatures ever degrade chemical compositions?

Space is cold, but that does not protect the Moons surface to heat up to 150 deg C. It would have to be stored in the section oriented permanently away from sun,and being isolated from warmer parts. Another question could be protection against ionizating ratioation.

@Poutnik medicines tend not to be very bulky and given their importance I assume they will be well shielded

Space isn't as cold as you might think.  Without an atmosphere, conduction and convection aren't a thing, so you don't lose heat quickly at all.  One of the bigger problems ends up being how to get rid of excess heat.

@cHao You still have heat radiation and apparent space temperature for radiation heat exchange is 0 K. This can be tackled down by low-emissivity outer surface.

Mars has no magnetic field so its daytime radiation levels are roughly the same as deep space. Because it’s night for half the time, overall exposure is about half of deep space, or 40-50 times surface Earth.

Not a medicine, but tin can permanently and infectiously deteriorate at low temperatures: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_pest

Lower temperature cannot degrade medicines faster in space since this goes against chemical kinetics and Arrhenius law; however low temperature can induce other undesirable changes in the solid state such as phase changes or glass transition and their corresponding solubility in the body. The major issue is time (shelf-life) and unfriendly UV and other forms of radiation that can fry humans and medicines on Mars despite being an extremely cold planet.

While it does not change the validity of your answer, note that the question stated "on a trip to Mars", not already on Mars. Radiation would presumably be an even greater concern on the way there. Also, the kinetics of phase changes should be very slow near absolute zero.

Buckthorn, glass transition is abrupt rather even at low temperature.

There are other considerations. For eample tablets use a binding agent and if that includes water it may freeze and physically disrupt it. So when used it becomes a powder and absorption rates in the body changes

Most tablets don't have water. Moisture is something which is to be avoided like a plague in dry tablet-formed pharmaceuticals.

There is some irony that the anti-radiation medicine might succumb to the radiation it is meant to protect you from.


can low temperatures ever degrade chemical compositions?

Some proteins, such as insulin, can become denatured by freezing.
According to Childrens Hospital of Philadelphia

The protein in frozen insulin denatures and won’t work in the same way.


Interesting. Is it really the protein that freezes (what does that even mean -- it is a fluid at room temperature?) or is it in an aqueous solution, and it's the water that freezes?

The shear forces when ice crystals form denature the protein. You can sometimes flash freeze or freeze in the presence of cryoprotectants such as glycerol to avoid denaturation. @Peter-ReinstateMonica

sacharids are sensitive too. Take a potato, freeze it. It becomes sweet because the polysacharids in starch get broken and ptyalin in your mouth can break them into mono- and di- sacharids that taste sweet.

@Karsten No doubt. But what I want to get at is that we have an aqueous solution (or suspension); what freezes is the water, not the insulin, and naturally, freezing water can damage all kinds of large molecules. I am not sure whether pure insulin is stable or can be produced at all (here is an article describing the role of water for storing it as hexameres in the human body; not sure whether monomeres would be stable without water).

Yes, cold temperatures can degrade medicines. For example, let's say there is a medicine in which active ingredients must be homogeneously dissolved in water. At lower temperatures, the solvation power of the water decreases, which can lead to a non-homogeneous mixture. In this non-homogeneous mixture, the active ingredients can form clumps, degrading the medicine.
Similarly, crystallization can occur, which also degrades the quality of the medicine. There are many factors that can lead to the degradation of medicine at lower temperatures.

I don't know what you mean by "solvation power of water", although it is true that it is more common for solubility to increase with T. In any case, your solubility argument would be true for formulations that are maintained in aqueous solution above the normal freezing point of water.

By solvation power, I mean the ability of a solvent to dissolve the solute. Some solvents lose some of their "solvation power", if there is an increase in temperature.

@SameerTahir, the temperature dependence of solubility is a function of (solvent, solute) pairs, not of the solvent alone.  For example, although many compounds' solubility in water decreases with decreasing temperature, the solubility of CO2 in water increases with decreasing temperature over a fairly wide range of temperatures interesting to humans.  There is no such thing as "solvation power" of a solvent independent of solute.

You are right, solubility is a function of both, solute and solvent. But some solvents can only dissolve solute if they are kept at lower temperatures. But yes solubility depends on both.

Some of the drugs have to be accessible on board the spacecraft. Perhaps there are cold modules where an additional supply can be stored but the formulation would have to be modified in some cases. You might ask how supplies might be safely transported outside passenger modules in the space exploration SE site.
The article refers to "terrestrial shelf-life data" with compounds stored under conventional conditions on Earth (perhaps refrigerated but often room temperature), not at near absolute zero. The effect of radiation is not the main question, it is formulation stability (for instance phase separation) and retaining the activity of the API which by degrading loses potency and generates unwanted compounds.
Like most engineering problems many issues are considered during formulation including cost, route and ease of administration, dose, potency, and stability. Like a $100 hammer (or is it 1 million these days?), the preparations might be reformulated to behave better under longer periods and more extreme conditions. Degradation decreases at lower temperatures for kinetic reasons (if not thermodynamic) but storing stuff at very low T might alter phase stability. It might be reasonable to take along ingredients that must be combined upon arrival to Mars or as needed along the way:

However, for inherently unstable drugs, preventive measures can include altering the dosage form in a number of ways. For liquid dosage forms, the hydrolysis of drugs is dependent on the presence of water, and thus storage of dry powders followed by reconstitution in water before dispensing minimizes hydrolysis. Similarly, if a drug is known to be susceptible to hydrolysis at room temperature, its storage in a cool place is advised, and patients can be counseled on this practice. Additionally, pharmacists should provide the correct labeling on the packaging.

Note also that this is not a pleasure cruise. Humans intending to undertake interplanetary travel are probably less risk averse than the average person. At minimum it is important to remain functional on board the spacecraft. Although mission failure due to an unstable formulation would be undesirable, some increased extent of API degradation under the duration of the journey might be acceptable, provided degradation compounds have limited side effects.  Bureaucratic hurdles would have to be overcome (somebody would have to sign off on allowing violation of FDA standards).

Most of chemicals (especially organic compounds) degrade at low temperatures. Just slower than at higher temperatures. So the question is not if, but how fast. As the rule of thumb there is the van't Hoff's rule the rate of chemical reactions increases typically 2-4 times by increasing temperature by $\pu{10 ^{\circ}C}$. For organic compounds would would count rather with 2 times.
Also, one thing is temperature of space background radiation 2.7 K, other thing is kinetic energy of interplanetary molecules ( with density of molecules $\approx \pu{5 cm-3}$ we cannot talk about their temperature), and yet another things is the effective temperature of space capsule surface, periodically exposed to Solar radiation. The capsule would have to rotate to simulate gravity and stabilize capsule orientation.
As cosmic radiation is very penetrating, it is not easy to shield it.

Yes, even simple binary compounds do. It is called eutectoid reaction if it can be reversed by simply raising the temperature again.
Notice that this is not applicable to the decomposition of drugs since most of them are molecular, and molecules do not form by raising the temperature.
Here is an example of binary phase diagram with an eutectoid: http://www-g.eng.cam.ac.uk/mmg/teaching/typd/addenda/eutectoidreaction1.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidocaine/prilocaine

@Mithoron Degrading a lattice into two other lattices at lower T is the topic of OP. Crystallization of a liquid, as your link suggests, into two solid phases isn't IMO a "degradation".

@Mithoron ...this is why I only mentioned eutectoid and didn't mention eutectics.

Cool ;) But you didn't need "@Mithoron" to ping - it's automatic when there's only one person to respond to. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Even pure metals do. Tin pest is nice example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_pest

@Crowley Given enough time, suitable binaries may separate two different elemental compositions by solid state diffusion. Tin pest degrades the lattice only. I'm not adding this to my answer. You can write your own answer.

Kaolin, used for stomach upsets and diarrhoea, is a clay which turns into crystals in low temperature and stays that way (making it useless as a medicine). You're not even allowed to put it in the fridge, and supposed to be careful if you leave it in the car in cold weather. Probably an unusual example.
