Is it OK to put unopened jars of creatine in freezer?
I purchased several jars and wonder whether it's OK to put some in the freezer. There is very little online about this, and one video says never do this and another webpage says it shouldn't hurt (though it probably won't extend the shelf life).
My concern is that I don't have (or need) air conditioning, even though it can get hot in the apartment. So there is no cool, dry place for creatine. I suppose I can put it in the fridge, but for me, that space is more of a premium than the freezer.
I'm hoping that whatever answer is given can be backed scientifically, preferably empirically, but I suppose that argumentation based on the chemistry is OK.

"I originally posted this at the Stack Exchange for physical fitness, but it was closed because the question was about chemistry.  Hoping it is OK to ask the question here." The question might not get a great reception but is not strictly off topic here (my opinion).

Do you have pure creatine or some kind of formulation?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/184103/do-some-chemicals-degrade-at-low-temperatures

One issue is condensation of water when you warm up substances stored in the freezer. One way to avoid this issue is to let containers sit at room temperature until the contents are at room temperature before opening the container.

@Mithoron: Thanks for the link.  I'm still not sure creatine is vulnerable.  I am not a chemist, but the chemical structure is shown at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatine

@Karsten: Agreed.  I stop freezing many things until I'm ready to use them, then I let the warm up before daily usage.

@Snijderfrey: It's creatine monohydrate in powder form: https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B08DH161T6

We are talking about creatine monohydrate and not about creatine being part of a formulation. If the creatine was part of a formulation, freezing could cause non-chemical changes such as phase separation.
That said, when thinking about storage conditions for creatine monohydrate, you can certainly store it in cold temperatures. For example, TCI sells this compound and recommends to store at "Room Temperature (Recommended in a cool and dark place, <$\pu{15 ^\circ C}$)" (see the product website). Sigma-Aldrich says storage temperature should be between $\pu{2 ^\circ C}$ and $\pu{30 ^\circ C}$ (see product website). I generally see no problem to go lower, such as $\pu{-20 ^\circ C}$, because thermal degradation will definitely be slower. The main issue with creatine however is its stability when in contact with water. The lower the temperature, the more likely it is to introduce moisture and thus degrade the creatine. So if you can make sure this does not happen there should be no problem. If you do not trust the packaging to be airtight, then you could put the container into an additional airtight container or a well-sealed plastic bag. And of course never open the container when the contents is still cold enough to induce water condensation. Then your creatine monohydrate should be safe.

Thanks.  I noticed that the 2nd link is to creatine mono-hydrate.  With the recommended storage temperatures that you posted, I am getting worried. Wikipedia says that it contains water  What do you mean by the thermal degradation will definitely be slower?  Do you mean the aging of the product at room temperature, or the possible adverse effects from freezing?

About air tightness, under the lid of the plastic jar is a paper seal that must be stabbed to break, which should slow the diffusion of any humidity from opening the freezer door.  I expect any humidity to condense out of the air before it reaches the paper seal.  So the only potential damage is the freezing of water in the "hydrate".  Is that something that was considered in your answer?  Thanks.
